# GNU make - could switching to diff version affect build output?

Tags: windows, multithreading, makefile, gnu-make

I'm current using GNU Make 3.81 `--jobs=1` but trying to migrate to GNU Make 4.2.1 `--jobs=X` i.e. multithreaded.

The makefiles, environment, etc **EVERYTHING** else is exactly the same.

**QUESTION**

Is it POSSIBLE for the `.obj`s or any artifacts to be different?

**UPDATE**

Assume the makefiles are logically correct meaning all the dependencies are correctly and thoroughly specified i.e. they're "parallel-correct"

Comment: Yes. Using a different version of `make` can be a reason. Parallel `make` is another potential reason, if your dependencies were not exhaustively described. Example: `foo.c` is first generated from `foo.l` and then compiled, producing `foo.o`. But you forgot to tell `make` that `foo.c` has `foo.l` as pre-requisite. It could be that, if `foo.l` changes, it worked (by accident) with `--jobs=1` but that now, with `--jobs=2`, `foo.c` is compiled before being updated.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet yes good catch! However I'm trying to isolate if merely changing the version of `make` will have an effect. So I've updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Makefiles are *parallel-correct*, differences cannot come from there.

But yes, using a different version of `make` can lead to different productions. There are hundreds of reasons, especially for such a long jump from one version to the other. Here is an example, coming from the release notes of version 3.82:

```
* WARNING: Backward-incompatibility!
  The library search behavior has changed to be compatible with the standard
  linker behavior. Prior to this version for prerequisites specified using
  the -lfoo syntax make first searched for libfoo.so in the current
  directory, vpath directories, and system directories. If that didn't yield
  a match, make then searched for libfoo.a in these directories. Starting
  with this version make searches first for libfoo.so and then for libfoo.a
  in each of these directories in order.
```

So, using version 3.82 instead of 3.81 can cause your linker to use different library files and thus to produce different binaries.

Listing all similar possibilities between 3.81 and 4.2.1 would be an enormous task.

Comment: Nice catch. My build team plans to run identical builds except for `make` version for couple months to prove there's no differences. Good to have possible explanation for differences.